# Huawei E353 Driver for Linux

Tags: drivers, usb, modem

Does the Linux kernel that comes with Ubuntu 12.04 support the Huawei E353 modem? I'm using it on Windows currently but want to know if it works on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 3):

Doing a search on Google for this, I (hopefully) found the answer to your question on: [Ubuntu Forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1799524). It shows the exact steps to download the E353.tar.gz file and shows the instructions on how to install it.

Comment: @BigGenius, does this answer fix your problem? If not, please say so that other people can help too, but if it does, accept it.

Comment: No this doesn't solve my problem.